# HTML progress bar using cherrypy and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, cherrypy

Hi there I am trying to develop a simple web-based file upload form with a progress bar. I'm using cherrypy 3.2 as the server and the file is being successfully uploaded. My problem is the fact that the progress bar appears but isn't updated in the web browser during the upload process. I know that the function prompt() is being called because an alert box is displayed when i click the upload button without selecting a file first.

I've included my code below. Please let me know if i'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**The sever side:**

```
class filedrop(object):
    def index(self):
        return open('index.html')
    index.exposed = True

    def upload_handler(self, myFile, mySize):
        fileName = os.path.split(myFile.filename)[1]
        chunksize = round(int(mySize)/10)
        fo = open('C:/Sprint 16/' + fileName, 'wb')
        while True:
            data = myFile.file.read(int(chunksize))
            if not data:
                sys.stderr.write("\n")
                break
            fo.write(data)
        fo.close()
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/")
    upload_handler.exposed = True
cherrypy.quickstart(filedrop())
```

**The 'index.html' file**

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <b>Upload Files To This Directory</b><br><br>
    <form id="form" action="upload_handler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Uform" onsubmit="return prompt()">
        <input type="file" name="myFile" id="upFile" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value=" Upload"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="mySize" id="fileSize"/>
    </form> <progress id="progBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    <script>
        function prompt(){
            var x=document.forms["Uform"]["myFile"].value;
            if(x==null || x==""){
                alert("No file chosen. Please go back and try again");
                return false;
            }
            var input = document.getElementById("upFile");
            var size = input.files[0].size;
            var sizeField = document.getElementById("fileSize");
            sizeField.value = size;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
            xhr.open("POST", "upload_handler");
        }
        function updateProgress(evt){
            if(evt.lengthComputable){
                var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
                var progressBar = document.getElementById("progBar");
                proressbar.value = percentComplete;                             
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: finally got it working... updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I got working...

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <b>Upload Files To This Directory</b><br><br>
    <!--<form id="form" action="/filedrop/upload_handler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Uform" onsubmit="return prompt()">-->
        <input type="file" name="myFile" id="upFile" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value=" Upload" onclick="prompt();"/>
    <!--    <input type="hidden" name="mySize" id="fileSize"/>
    </form>--> <progress id="progBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    <script>
        function prompt(){
            var x=document.getElementById("upFile").value;
            if(x==null || x==""){
                alert("No file chosen. Please go back and try again");
                return false;
            }
            var input = document.getElementById("upFile");
            //var size = input.files[0].size;
            //var sizeField = document.getElementById("fileSize");
            //sizeField.value = size;

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('myFile', document.getElementById("upFile").files[0]);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
            xhr.open("POST", "upload_handler");
            xhr.send(data);
        }
        function updateProgress(evt){
            if(evt.lengthComputable){
                var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
                var progressBar = document.getElementById("progBar");
                progressBar.value = percentComplete;                             
            }
        }
        </script>
</body>
```

*.py file reads:

```
import cherrypy
import os

class filedrop(object):
    def index(self):
        return open('index.html')
    index.exposed = True

    def upload_handler(self, myFile):
        fo = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/" + myFile.filename, 'wb')
        all_data = bytearray()
        while True:
            data = myFile.file.read(8192)
            all_data += data
            if not data:
                break
        fo.write(all_data)
        fo.close()
        #raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/")
     upload_handler.exposed = True
cherrypy.quickstart(filedrop())
```

I believe the problems were that proressbar was misspelled in the bottom of your script tag, the form was posting and taking you off the page that was giving the progress update and you weren't really sending the file to the server side.  Let me know if you have any more problems.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Andrew, just tried what you suggested and unfortunately it made no difference to the progress bar. Thanks anyway

Comment: Updated my answer... try this.

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't make a difference. I feel like i'm missing something very obvious but i don't know what it is. I really appreciate your attempts to help. Thanks

Comment: I see a problem... i believe your form submit is bypassing your js.  I updated the form tag to say onsubmit="return prompt();" See if that helps.

Comment: Hi Andrew if you scroll to the right of my form you'll see that onsubmit is already included in the form. That is why i mentioned in the question that the js function prompt() is definitely being called because I've tried uploading without selecting a file for upload and the js alert box pops up in my browser

Comment: how big is the file you're uploading?  Is it small and happening too faster to see the progress bar?

Comment: I'm testing the upload with a 25MB video (wmv) file. I don't think that's too small

Comment: I've tested the following browsers as well: Internet explorer 11, Chrome 32 and Firefox 27. Still no activity on the progress bar

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks a lot, I'll mark your answer as correct. I tried it out and it worked. The HTTP redirect wasn't actually the problem. It was more to do with the functions within the script tag. Thanks again